# Fetching the values from mongodb collection using java

Tags: java, mongodb

These are 2 different collections in a database.I am not able to figure out how to dynamically fetch the values from the collections using java .

I want to fetch the values through java program but without using the 
hardcoded values like "VerifyEmail.LicenseKey" & "wsf:status.arg0.age" as mentioned above in the java code.Is there a way to fetch the values without hardcoding in java.

Collection 1:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("583567ac6c85e71adc1f8bae"),
"wsf:status" : {
    "arg0" : {
        "name" : "James",
        "phonenum" : NumberLong(9848222338),
        "age" : 18
        "status" : "N" 
       }
   },
 }
```

Query 1:
Here I am using the hardcoded values to fetch the desired result from the collection 1.

`db.xmlcoll1.find({"wsf:status.arg0.age":18})`

Collection 2:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("582446686c85e73a70696666"),

"VerifyEmail" : {
    "xmlns" : "http://ws.cdyne.com/",
    "email" : "james@yahoo.com",
    "LicenseKey" : 123
} }
```

Query 2:

Here I am using the hardcoded value of the element "VerifyEmail"
to fetch the values.

`db.xmlcoll.find({"VerifyEmail.LicenseKey":123});`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Morphia](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.2/getting-started/quick-tour/) if performance is not critical for you. And use such constructions for queries:

```
underpaid = datastore.createQuery(Employee.class)
                 .field("age").lessThanOrEq(18)
                 .asList();
```

Comment: How would look your expected query?

Comment: `BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();`  `query.put("wsf:status.arg0.status", "N"); `                                         `DBObject result = collection.findOne(query);`                                    this is the query.But  I am  not able to figure out how to fetch "wsf:status.arg0" from the collection without making it static.

Comment: so... you want quirey document, get it's structure and use it without declaring manually in code for following quireies, am I right?

Comment: Yeah is that possible ?